# How can I have an attachment open up in a new window from a sharepoint custom webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have enabled attachment in my custom Web Part like below:

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
      <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ListId">
             {} </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
          <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

How can i add `target="blank"`?

Comment: This is the html output.
<a href="/sites/Logo.jpg" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '0', '');return false;" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, '0', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '');return false;" tabindex="1" target="_blank">Logo.jpg</a>
As you can see i tried adding target="blank" but still opens on the same windoew.
Thanks sin Advance

Comment: I have fixed this issue by using jquery and removed the onclick events.
Cheers